# always fail to set password for an account by using ansible

Tags: ansible

```
ansible all -i localhost, -m debug -a "msg={{ 'apassword' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
```

output:

```
$6$mysecretsalt$zBxKrtoLhJ5.ng.yl/fEzEydPGmEruaDLH1Bt7uLqumt8SDFjhxGGwm7bzQoQODGkNhY.GhYf2zBdncB8gH4s0
```

And then:

```
ansible app -m user -a "name=alice password=$6$mysecretsalt$zBxKrtoLhJ5.ng.yl/fEzEydPGmEruaDLH1Bt7uLqumt8SDFjhxGGwm7bzQoQODGkNhY.GhYf2zBdncB8gH4s0"
```

`ssh alice@ip`, by using "appssword", it fails, while using `passwd` command I can login.